# Django and postgis on postgres using openshift v3

Tags: django, openshift, postgis

I am new to openshift v3 and am trying to deploy a django application that uses a postgres backend. I used the example https://github.com/openshift/django-ex as a starting point, wherein I removed the sample app and added my own app and code. I am using an edited version of the template django-postgresql-persistent.json to deploy the application from a private repo.

When I try to deploy, the django container crashes whereas the postres container is deployed, albeit with some issues.

The app uses geo search and I am encountering what I see as three issues:

Issue #1. I do not think that Postgis is installed and enabled as an extension on the postgres db. I tried the below:

```
postgres=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();                                                                                             
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist                                                                                
LINE 1: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();                                                                                                
               ^                                                                                                                      
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.                              
postgres=# SELECT version();                                                                                                          

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                         
 PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit                          
(1 row)                                                                                                                               

postgres=# SELECT PostGIS_version();                                                                                                  
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist                                                                                     
LINE 1: SELECT PostGIS_version();                                                                                                     
               ^                                                                                                                      
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.                              
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;                                                                                                  
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/share/pgsql/extension/postgis.control": No such file o
r directory
```

Question: How do I install PostGIS? I do not seem to have sudo privileges or to be able to use yum?

Issue 2: The deployment log on the django container is given below. It seems to be missing the GEOS lib. This did not present itself as a problem on my virtual environment locally. How do I install these libs / dependencies? Can it be done using requirements.txt? 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: GEOS is required and has not been detected. Are you sure it is installed?

Issue 3: If one did intend to serve static files. How does one address the warnings then?
Thank you.

```
> ---> Installing application source ...
> ---> Installing dependencies ... Collecting appdirs==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) Downloading
> appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting Django==1.8.6 (from -r
> requirements.txt (line 2)) Downloading
> Django-1.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB) Collecting
> django-cors-headers==2.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
> Downloading django_cors_headers-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting
> django-debug-toolbar==1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
> Downloading django_debug_toolbar-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (204kB)
> Collecting gunicorn==19.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
> Downloading gunicorn-19.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB) Collecting
> olefile==0.44 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) Downloading
> olefile-0.44.zip (74kB) Collecting packaging==16.8 (from -r
> requirements.txt (line 7)) Downloading
> packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting Pillow==4.1.1 (from -r
> requirements.txt (line 8)) Downloading Pillow-4.1.1.tar.gz (11.3MB)
> Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
> Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB) Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0
> (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) Downloading
> pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB) Collecting six==1.10.0
> (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) Downloading
> six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting sqlparse==0.2.3 (from -r
> requirements.txt (line 12)) Downloading
> sqlparse-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting whitenoise==3.0 (from
> -r requirements.txt (line 13)) Downloading whitenoise-3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Installing collected packages:
> appdirs, Django, django-cors-headers, sqlparse, django-debug-toolbar,
> gunicorn, olefile, six, pyparsing, packaging, Pillow, psycopg2,
> whitenoise Running setup.py install for olefile Running setup.py
> install for Pillow Running setup.py install for psycopg2 Successfully
> installed Django-1.8.6 Pillow-4.1.1 appdirs-1.4.3
> django-cors-headers-2.0.2 django-debug-toolbar-1.5 gunicorn-19.4.5
> olefile-0.44 packaging-16.8 psycopg2-2.6.1 pyparsing-2.2.0 six-1.10.0
> sqlparse-0.2.3 whitenoise-3.0 You are using pip version 7.1.2, however
> version 9.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip
> install --upgrade pip' command.
> ---> Collecting Django static files ... WARNING: could not run 'manage.py collectstatic'. To debug, run: $ python ./manage.py
> collectstatic --noinput Ignore this warning if you're not serving
> static files with Django. chgrp: changing group of
> ‘/opt/app-root/include/python3.5m’: Operation not permitted chgrp:
> changing group of ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/copy.py’: Operation not
> permitted chgrp: changing group of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/token.py’: Operation not permitted ... 
> ... chgrp: changing group of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py’: Operation not permitted
> chgrp: changing group of ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/keyword.py’:
> Operation not permitted chgrp: changing group of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py’: Operation not permitted
> chgrp: changing group of ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/base64.py’:
> Operation not permitted ... chgrp: changing group of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/functools.py’: Operation not permitted
> chgrp: changing group of ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/config-3.5m’:
> Operation not permitted ... chmod: changing permissions of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/abc.py’: Operation not permitted chmod:
> changing permissions of ‘/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/heapq.py’:
> Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/_collections_abc.py’: Operation not
> permitted chmod: changing permissions of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/warnings.py’: Operation not permitted
> chmod: changing permissions of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload’: Operation not permitted
> chmod: changing permissions of
> ‘/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux’: Operation not permitted
> Running post commit hook ... sh: cannot set terminal process group
> (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device sh: no job control in this shell
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./manage.py", line 10, in
> <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
>     django.setup()   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line
> 18, in setup
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 108, in populate
>     app_config.import_models(all_models)   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 198, in import_models
>     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in
> import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in
> exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
> line 41, in <module>
>     class Permission(models.Model):   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 139, in __new__
>     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 324, in add_to_class
>     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> line 250, in contribute_to_class
>     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File
> "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py",
> line 36, in __getattr__
>     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line
> 241, in __getitem__
>     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line
> 112, in load_backend
>     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in
> import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in
> exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py",
> line 8, in <module>
>     from .features import DatabaseFeatures   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures   File
> "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py",
> line 3, in <module>
>     from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py",
> line 12, in <module>
>     django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: GEOS is required and has not been detected. Are you sure it is installed? See also
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/
> error: build error: container
> "openshift_s2i-build_django-psql-persistent-2_second-deploy_post-commit_0a7f4e7f"
> returned non-zero exit code: 1
```

Comment: Did you look at the link in the error

Comment: yes, that is the Issue 2. It seems that the GEOS lib is required by Geodjango. However I am unable to access the terminal running the django app as that container crashes post a failed deployment.

Comment: You can run ``oc debug dc/yourappname`` to get a shell in container, without the application being run. You can then dig around and see what is installed. If the GEOS lib is a system lib, it is probably simply not present. You as a result would need to create a custom S2I image builder which includes it. If you are doing that on OpenShift Online, you can't build Docker images in the OpenShift instance and would need to create that custom image separately and host it on an external registry. Similar for database image.

Comment: Thanks Graham. Am trying the custom image approach.

Comment: A couple of follow up questions: 1) Do we need to use S2I image builder or is that optional?     2) Can I build the image in openshift online using a dockerfile or must I use a pre-built image hosted externally. You seem to have already answered this one but I did want to confirm again.